# CSV file not visible properly

Tags: export-to-csv

I export a csv file from php application program. i open the CSV file edit some data and save the data, all data appear in 1 column instead of several columns. unable to import this file again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What program are you editing it in - Excel? Have you tried looking at the file in a text editor before and after editing to see what's changed?

Comment: It would open with properly in text-editer. but not in csv file. i need to import the csv file after editing. but all the value shows in single cell in a row.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "It would open with properly in text-editer. but not in csv file."

Comment: yes, me too it'll open in text-editer properly. but not in csv file. how to solve this. cause i need to reuse this csv file after editing.

Answer (score 0):

Export the CSV with `;` as separator instead of `,`

Comment: ya i tried this too. it will print like this in single cell.  
121200000,"rajan","123456789","7000","SELF","SELF","","","".. this need to print cell by cell beside cells